# Need to determine some columns while creating an excel file via .bat

Tags: excel, batch-file

So I want to make an excel file with inputting some info into batch file. It is ok until here. But my problem is I want to seperate those `infos` into some specified columns.

```
@echo off

set /p VarOne=Isim girin: 
set /p VarTwo=Soyisim girin: 
set /p VarThree=Mudurluk girin: 
set /p VarFour=IP girin: 

echo %VarOne%          %VarTwo%         %VarThree%          %VarFour% >> %C:\test%\test.csv

echo Dosya kaydedildi. %C:\test%
pause
```

As a **basic example,** I want to put "`VarOne`" into "`A`" column in excel file, "`VarTwo`" into "`B`" column etc.

Comment: @Hellboy.. Just No. you cannot link a possible duplicate to a question with no excepted answer.

Comment: @Kaan **CSV** files are **C**omma-**S**eparated **V**alues files, and not excel files. Excel files are Tab delimited, but you cannot write from Cmdline to xls file as they are not plain text.

Comment: Your file is written with tabs in anyway, excel does not actually see the tabs as it can see the csv file format. Opeing the file with notepad displays the tabs. One way to ACTUALLY write to xls is using [powershell](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/137203-create-an-excel-file-from-within-powershell)

Comment: lastly, you are writing to `%C:\test%` which does not exist, please remove the `%` on either side.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard So from what I did understand, I simply cant do what I just wanted to do with this .bat file ?

Comment: You can, but not tab delimited using batch only, rather use vbsript or perhaps powershell to do this.

Comment: Please read Wikipedia article about [Comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) which explains how to format a CSV file right. Then open from Windows __Control Panel - Region and Languages__ (Windows 7) and click on tab __Formats__ on button __Advanced__ which shows on tab __Numbers__ the *List separator* which Excel interprets by default for your user account according to this configuration on reading data from a *.csv file.

Comment: Further read Microsoft documentation for [Text Import Wizard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-import-wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857) which Excel has since at least Excel 97. I found out something interesting by chance 1 month ago. If a *.csv file is Unicode encoded in UTF-16 Little Indian with BOM instead of ANSI encoded as usual, Excel 2003 and later versions use on opening the CSV file the functions of text import wizard and detect automatically the tab also as list separator independent on which list separator is configured in the region settings.

Comment: Excel 97 supports also tab separated and UTF-16 LE encoded *.csv files, but first shows an error message because of unknown data format. After user clicked on button OK on this message, the text import wizard is also used by Excel 97 to read the data without any further user interaction. Excel 2000 behavior on UTF-16 LE encoded CSV file not yet tested by me.